# Mysql multi source replication configuration issue

Tags: mysql, replication

I need to replicate different MySQL databases from multiple servers into a single slave server. How can this be done?

I have a server 1 where i have two database A,B which i need to replicate the complete databases to slave.

and on server 2 where i have one database C where i need to replicate only two tables in the slave.

so this is the configuration i did in the slave, but its not working for me in case of

```
server-id=950
binlog_format=row
log-bin=mysql-bin
skip-slave-start
gtid-mode=on
enforce-gtid-consistency
log-slave-updates
master-info-repository=TABLE
relay-log-info-repository=TABLE
replicate-do-db=A
replicate-do-db=B
replicate-do-table=C.tbl_name1
replicate-do-table=C.tbl_name2
```

even tried with

```
replicate-do-table=channel_1:C.tbl_name1
replicate-do-table=channel_1:C.tbl_name2
```

Please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Channel based replication filter is introduced in MySQL 8.0. So it won't work in MySQL 5.7

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-rules-channel-based-filters.html